# Symfony file field empty on edit

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I am reading for a while about this but found nothing that works for me. 
This is entity

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 *
 * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Molimo unesite PDF ili Word fajl.")
 * @Assert\File(mimeTypes={ "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation", "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint", "application/pdf", "application/msword", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"})
 */
private $body;
```

This is form

```
// Problem with empty field on edit persist! Form expect FileType but db sends string!!!
            ->add('body', FileType::class,  [
                //'data_class' => null,// <-- If I change it nothing happened.
                'label' => 'Word ili pdf dokument',
                'invalid_message' =>'Id posta nije validan',
                'attr' => [
                    'class' => 'form-group',
        ]])
```

Everything is very simple and made following docs. I have entity that contains few properties one of them for files ($body). Files are set to be saved in web/uploads/post/ .  When I go to edit page  I get this error:

*"The form's view data is expected to be an instance of class Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File, but is a(n) string. You can avoid this by setting the "data_class" option to null or by adding a view transformer that transforms a string to an instance of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File".*

If i set data_status => null field is empty.

What I need is some link to example with this working, Data Transformer maybe?

Comment: Actually any suggestion is welcome!

Comment: Could you please give us a little more information about the problem you are facing?

Comment: I made some edits. If there is any information needed I am ready to write.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get around this by creating a new File() in your editAction. Like this:

```
/**
 * @Route("/edit/{yourEntity}", name="entity_edit")
 * 
 * @return Response
 */
public function editAction(Request $request, YourEntity yourEntity)
{
    $body = new File($this->getParameter('your_files_directory') . '/' . $yourEntity->getBody());
    $yourEntity->setBody($body);
    // rest of your editAction
}
```

Comment: Thanks! After I implemented your code. I still got file field empty but after i removed that field from the form there was no exeption on edit . Not good, I know, but I really do need to change name of file ever. Thanks once more!

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same problem in my edit action and solved it by submitting the form manually with the clearMissing parameter set to false instead of using `$form->handleRequest($request);`, as explained on https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/direct_submit.html:

```
if ($request->isMethod('POST'))
{
    $form->submit($request->request->get($form->getName()),false);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid())
    {
```

This way, the original value of file will not be set to null in case you aren't submitting a new file.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, solved. The answer from @ASOlivieri is good with one small modification. Code in his answer will remember path with file name. So if you want to edit it again it will throw not found exeption. You have to ->setBody again, to be the same as original file name. Set it before flush()

```
public function editAction(Request $request, Post $post) {
    $fileName = $post->getBody();
    $file = new File($this->getParameter('post_directory') . '/' . $post->getBody());
    $post->setBody($file);

    $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($post);
    $editForm = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\PostEditType', $post);
    $editForm->handleRequest($request);


    if ($editForm->isSubmitted() && $editForm->isValid()) {

        $post->setBody($fileName);
        $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 0):

In my case what helped was:

```
if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
        $form->submit($request->request->get($form->getName()));
        if ($form->isValid()) {...
```

to

```
$form->handleRequest($request);
if ($form->isSubmitted()) {
     if ($form->isValid()) { ...
```